# How can I optimize my nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I have nginx .conf file as below; I'm wondering if it can be write simpler:

*default.conf*

```
upstream docsapp {
    server app:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/admin/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/api/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api-token-auth/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/api-token-auth/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /docs/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/docs/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        alias /usr/local/src/app/media/;
        internal;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/local/src/app/static/;
    }

    client_max_body_size 8M;

}
```

Location `\` is Vue.js app, remaining is Django REST Framework. I've searched a web for a while but none of found solutions worke for me.

Another problem occurred during attempt to split this file into two:

*vue.conf*

```
server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    }

}
```

and

*drf.conf*

```
upstream docsapp {
    server app:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/admin/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/api/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api-token-auth/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/api-token-auth/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /docs/ {
        proxy_pass http://docsapp/docs/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /media/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        alias /usr/local/src/app/media/;
        internal;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/local/src/app/static/;
    }

    client_max_body_size 8M;

}
```

It also didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since you do not change request URI when you proxy requests to the `docsapp` upstream, you can replace four `location` blocks where `proxy_pass` directive used with the following one:

```
location ~ ^/(?:admin|api|api-token-auth|docs)/ {
    proxy_pass http://docsapp;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

You can't split your `server` block in two, only one of them will work acting as **default** server (see the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)).